KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_certificate_authentication in Synapse notebook
I am trying to use app with certificate for authentication in KustoConnectionStringBuilder, the certificate is saved in a KeyVault, as I found from the examples in github is required to download the PEM file as shown in the code below:
filename = "path to a PEM certificate"
with open(filename, "r") as pem_file:
    PEM = pem_file.read()

thumbprint = "certificate's thumbprint"
kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_certificate_authentication(cluster, client_id, PEM, thumbprint, authority_id)

Could someone point me in how to properly retrieve the certificate from the KeyVault in Synapse, I tried using DefaultAzureCredentials and looks is not supported in Synapse, is there any way to retrieve the cer file using linked service of the KeyVault?


DefaultAzureCredentials and looks are not supported in Synapse. Is there any way to retrieve the .cer file using a linked service of the KeyVault?

You can follow the procedure below to retrieve a certificate from the key vault:

Create a service principal, create a secret, save TenantId, ClientId, and Secret values. Add the Key Vault Administrator role in the key vault to the service principal by selecting IAM and clicking on Add and select Add role assignment.



Select the Key Vault Administrator role and go to the next step. Select the user or group option and click on the select member option. Select the SPN and click on the Review + Assign option.



Use the code below to get the details of the certificate in a Synapse notebook:

from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.certificates import CertificateClient

credential = ClientSecretCredential("<tenant_id>", "<client_id>", "<client_secret>")
certificate_client = CertificateClient(vault_url="https://<keyVaultName>.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)
certificate = certificate_client.get_certificate("<certificateName>")

print(certificate.name)
print(certificate.properties.version)
print(certificate.policy.issuer_name)

This will retrieve the details successfully, as shown below:

For more information, you can refer to this.

I cannot use secrets for the credentials, is there any way to do this using Linked Services?

I have provided the code to get cirtificate details not for secret.

you get the certificate from the key vault using secret auth with the ClientSecretCredential

ADAIK, To get certificate you should follow above approach.
